# Permission system with hooks and php

Tags: php

I have made a hook system which pretty simple can be invoked.

If i invoke something, the response is returned as an array where the different responses is merged into each other eg. array(responsefromhook1,responsefromhook2,..)

I would now like to make a access system which uses this hook architecture, but what is the best way to obtain the answer? I i say hook::invoke('user_write') it obviously returns true if even if the values in the array is false. I know i can make a "foreach" in the model handling the request, but then i will have to change the code in everywhere i have invoked something.

Advice would be much appreciated!